# Solving degree 3 polynomial to get real root

Tags: polynomials, roots

Get the real number $z$ such that $z^3 - 63z - 162 = 0$ using Cardano's method.

I haven't learned about Cardano's method how can I get the real number $z$ that is a root of the following polynomial?

Comment: A step by step of Cardano's method can be found at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Cardano.27s_method). For equations without the $z^2$ term (like here) this simply reduces to making the substitution $z = x  + \frac{63}{3x}$ which will give you a qubic equation in $x^3$.

Comment: A quadratic equation in $x^3$, right?

Comment: Yes, it should be *a quadratic equation in $x^3$* in my comment above.